# C slow function call

Tags: c

How can i have my functions in another c file without losing execution time ?

```
strcpy:                 0.485000
strcpyFunc:             0.469000
strcpyFuncInAnotherC:   2.015000
```

Have even tried with inline, but it seem it have never inline anything because the exe file keep his small size, and time were the same.

I compile with mingw32-gcc under code::block

Im learning C, many thanks for helping me understanding how to right handle a project with many .c files...

Here the bench code (have done without main.h)

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>//for GetTickCount

#include "func.h"

void double2str(const double x, char *buf) {
    sprintf(buf, "%.6f", x);
    }
double milliTick(void) {
    return GetTickCount()/1000.0;
    }
double timeDiff(const double start, const double end) {
    return end-start;
    }

void strcpyFunc(char *buf, const char *str) {
    strcpy(buf, str);
    }

int main() {
    char buf64[24];
    char buf[1024];
    char bufBench[32];
    char *sample = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    double timeStart1=0, timeEnd1=0;
    double timeStart2=0, timeEnd2=0;
    double timeStart3=0, timeEnd3=0;

    size_t len = 99999999;
    size_t i = 0;

    timeStart1 = milliTick();
    while(i < len) {
        strcpy(bufBench, sample);
        i++;
        }
    timeEnd1 = milliTick();

    i = 0;
    timeStart2 = milliTick();
    while(i < len) {
        strcpyFunc(bufBench, sample);
        i++;
        }
    timeEnd2 = milliTick();

    i = 0;
    timeStart3 = milliTick();
    while(i < len) {
        strcpyFuncInAnotherC(bufBench, sample);
        i++;
        }
    timeEnd3 = milliTick();

    strcpy(buf, "");
    double2str(timeDiff(timeStart1,timeEnd1), buf64);
    strcat(buf, "strcpy:\t\t\t");
    strcat(buf, buf64);
    strcat(buf, "\n");
    double2str(timeDiff(timeStart2,timeEnd2), buf64);
    strcat(buf, "strcpyFunc:\t\t");
    strcat(buf, buf64);
    strcat(buf, "\n");
    double2str(timeDiff(timeStart3,timeEnd3), buf64);
    strcat(buf, "strcpyFuncInAnotherC:\t");
    strcat(buf, buf64);
    strcat(buf, "\n");

    printf(buf);

    return 0;
    }
```

**func.h**

```
#ifndef HEADER_FUNC_H
#define HEADER_FUNC_H

void strcpyFuncInAnotherC(char *buf, const char *str);

#endif
```

**func.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "func.h"

void strcpyFuncInAnotherC(char *buf, const char *str) {
    strcpy(buf, str);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us the command line you are using to compile the code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are compiling to object files, ala:

```
gcc -O3 -o main.o main.c
gcc -O3 -o func.o func.c
gcc -O3 -o a.out main.o func.o
```

Then the compiler will optimize each object file (main and func), but cannot optimize the files when they're pieced together.

There's a reason for this: some projects have hundreds of object files and doing global optimization would greatly increase compile times. This, in turn, would make iterative testing difficult.

You can, however, force what's called "[link-time" or "interprocedural" optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interprocedural_optimization):

```
gcc -O3 -flto -o main.o main.c
gcc -O3 -flto -o func.o func.c
gcc -O3 -flto -o a.out main.o func.o
```

The compiler should now behave as if all the code had been in one source file to begin with. (`-flto` stands for "link-time optimization")

Comment: Thanks all for all your suggestions, i will investigate in this way...
I do not write by hand the commands, its code::block that do
And adding just the command line -flto to the building option give me these errors :

Comment: mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -Wconversion -ftrapv -Wtype-limits -Wstrict-overflow=5 -fstrict-overflow -Wsign-compare -flto -O3 -c "C:\Dev\Win32\FuncSpeed\func.c" -o obj\Release\func.o

Comment: mingw32-gcc.exe -Wall -Wconversion -ftrapv -Wtype-limits -Wstrict-overflow=5 -fstrict-overflow -Wsign-compare -flto -O3 -c "C:\Dev\Win32\FuncSpeed\main.c" -o obj\Release\main.o

Comment: mingw32-g++.exe -o bin\Release\FuncSpeed.exe obj\Release\func.o obj\Release\main.o -s

Comment: lto1.exe: internal compiler error: cannot read LTO decls from obj\Release\func.o

Comment: lto-wrapper: mingw32-g++.exe returned 1 exit status

Comment: ld.exe: lto-wrapper failed

Comment: I get it working by updating MinGW GCC 4.9.2 to 5.1.0 Really nice there is a solution for these time leak, very thanks!

Comment: @lainderon: I'm glad I could help. Good luck.